# phonegap push notification without GCM google cloud messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, android-notifications, chrome-gcm

It is possible to implement notification push in phonegapp without passing to google cloud messaging?
I could find just the plugins that use gcm like this:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
exist a different solution without passing to gcm??

Comment: Hi did you found a solution for that? We have a system server with an app in a local network witch is not online. So we try to implement a offlne local pusher notification server. Can you help?

Comment: What is your reason for not using GCM? Is it because your device is not connected to the Internet? If so, consider Pushy (pushy.me), a paid push notification gateway that can be self-hosted on-premises and supports Phonegap. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.